# Why document.write not writing in array format?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a nested array using `document.write` but it is writing only `4` instead of `[[4]]`. What can be the reason for this?

```js
document.write([[4]])
```

Comment: Did you search any article for this, Please don't delete your question, if you get any down-votes , I am searching for this.

Comment: [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) `[...]the toString method joins the array and returns one string containing each array element separated by commas. JavaScript calls the toString method automatically when an array is to be represented as a text value or when an array is referred to in a string concatenation.[...]` and `[4].toString()`  is `4`.

Comment: Why are you using `document.write()` in the 21st century?

Comment: @Barmar not using just experimenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

> A string containing the text to be written to the document.

It converts the response of `write` function into `String`

and String of `[[4]]` is `4`

```js
console.log(String([[4]]));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because the string representation of `[[4]]` is `4`:

```js
console.log([[4]].toString())
```

You can do what you want with `document.write(JSON.stringify([[4]]))`:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([[4]]))
```

Or if you need a prettier format: `document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify([[4]],null,4) + '</pre>' )`

```js
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify([[4]],null,4) + '</pre>' )
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.write(`<pre> ${JSON.stringify([[4]])} </pre>`)
```